# c++ multilevel inheritance not working

Tags: c++, inheritance

I can't seem to get multilevel inheritance function calls working properly. For my structure I have a "Entity" as the main super class then

Entity -> Bullet, Agent

Agent -> Player, Enemy

Enemy -> BasicEnemy

In each of these I have an "update" function

```
class Entity
{
public:
    Entity();
    virtual ~Entity();
    //stuff
    virtual Bullet update(float deltaTime);
 }


class Agent : public Entity
{
public:
    Agent();
    virtual ~Agent();

    virtual Bullet update(float deltaTime);

class Player : public Agent
{
public:
    Player();
    ~Player();

    Bullet update(float deltaTime) override;

class Enemy : public Agent
{
public:
    Enemy();
    virtual ~Enemy();

    virtual Bullet update(float deltaTime);

class BasicEnemy : public Enemy
{
public:
    BasicEnemy();
    ~BasicEnemy();

    Bullet update(float deltaTime) override;
```

I create player, enemy, and bullet objects then pass them into a vector of entities however whenever I call

```
Entity entity = entities[i];
entity.update(deltaTime);
```

It only every goes into the "Agent" update function and if i make the Agent update function pure virtual it just goes to the Entity update function, why don't the player and enemy update functions overwrite the base functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you store *objects* in the vector. You should store *object's pointers*.

Details:
In C++ if you cast an `Agent` *object* to an `Entity` *object* you loose all the information about the `Agent` and the new object will be a real `Entity`. I.e. you loose the polymorphic behavior.

This happened when you created a vector with `Entity` object and pushed and `Agent` object in it because the stored objects will be pure `Entity` objects.

In C++ the references and the pointers keep the polymorphism. Therefore to solve the issue you should create a vector of pointers:

```
std::vector< Entity* > entities;
entities.push_back( new Agent( ) );
entities[ 0 ]->update( 5); // Agent::update will be called
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing

Comment: Supplementary reading: [What is object slicing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)